# Azure service bus cannot create topic from Azure portal

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

When I create Service Bus it doesn't allow me to Add new Topic

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Verify namespace you're creating is not on the [Basic tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/). Basic tier doesn't have topics. If that's not the case, then Azure support is the only option to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Imagine if the tooltip of the grayed out `+ Topic` button on the Azure portal said _Topics are only available on the Standard and Premium tiers_ instead of just _Topic_…

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is a problem that the Basic tier is also called "Standard", so be aware of that!

[image]

Comment: Still an issue in 2021 - just wasted half an hour to find out why Standard doesn't work as expected... :D

Comment: Still an issue in 2022 - I switched to the English version now in the hopes of avoiding such painful sh** in the future.